# Should I unregister from TransactionScope TransactionCompleted event?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

Generally when registering events in .net, it is a good practice to unregister them when the object no longer needed to avoid memory leak.

What is the case for using TransactionScope's TransactionCompleted event?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += OnTransactionCompleted;

    // do something

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Looking when should I unregister the 'TransactionCompleted' event,

If I do this at the end of the using statement, it is guaranteed that the event handler already executed?

Other option is to unregister at the event handler itself, but i'm not sure another TransactionScope won't get started till then.

When does TransactionCompleted event get raised? can I be sure that it will be raised when the scope object finish disposal? (leave the 'using' block)

I don't see any reference to this in the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) nor in the [source code](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/tx/System/Transactions/TransactionScope@cs/1305376/TransactionScope@cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do this at the end of the using statement, it is guaranteed that
>   the event handler already executed?

No, because it might be a nested scope. There is only one transaction active at a time and it is managed by the outermost scope.

> can I be sure that it will be raised when the scope object finish disposal?

For the same reason, no. It is raised when the transaction commits which is normally when the outermost scope is disposed.

You don't need to unregister the event handler because transactions are short-lived objects that are not reused.